# mktime : unexpected result

Tags: c, tm, mktime

I want to convert a `struct tm` to a `time_t` with `mktime` in `c`.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
struct tm _tm;
time_t _t;

  strptime ("20160220", "%Y%m%d", &_tm);
  printf ("1: struct tm => %04d%02d%02d\n", _tm.tm_year+1900
                                          , _tm.tm_mon+1
                                          , _tm.tm_mday);

  _t = mktime(&_tm);
  printf ("2: struct tm => %04d%02d%02d | time_t: %lu\n"
                                                  , _tm.tm_year+1900
                                                  , _tm.tm_mon+1
                                                  , _tm.tm_mday
                                                  , _t);

  _tm = *(localtime(&_t));
  printf ("3: struct tm => %04d%02d%02d | time_t: %lu\n"
                                                  , _tm.tm_year+1900
                                                  , _tm.tm_mon+1
                                                  , _tm.tm_mday
                                                  , _t);
  return 0;
}
```

But it give me an unexpected output:

```
1: struct tm => 20160220
2: struct tm => 24941121 | time_t: 16563985201
3: struct tm => 24941121 | time_t: 16563985201
```

Apparently the value of `_tm` changes in `mktime`, and it returns an incorrect value.
What I'm doing wrong?
I compile it (64bit) on a linux system with `gcc` version 4.9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have undefined behavior because the `_tm` isn't correctly initialized.

Function strptime will only set the members specified in the format string, others will be left unmodified, thus their values will be indeterminate.

Then the function mktime will fix the values that are not in the range thus giving you a vastly different time, because of uninitialized member values in `_tm`.

The solution is to initialize correctly:

```
struct tm _tm = { 0 };
```

(And don't use prefix `_` in names, as it is reserved by C)

Comment: Thanks, Stupid of me. Concerns prefix _ => I have applied a bit too much copy/paste from include files.